# ¿Cómo volver al archivo index.php con javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un registro y necesito que al darle al botón inicio me regrese a el archivo `index.php` pero el archivo de registro esta dentro de una carpeta llamada vistas, y el `index` se encuentra en la raíz del sistema.

Acá les coloco el código:

`index.php`

```
<?php 
  include 'header.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Ventas</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="satur">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/style.css">
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

`header.php`

```
 <header>
    <nav class="navegacion">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Categorias</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Motocicletas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Celulares</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computadores</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
        <li><a href="#">Ingresar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Registrarse</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="vistas/registro_usuario.php">Nuevo Usuario</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">E-mail</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

El código de el archivos `javascript` que utilizo para regresar es:

```
function regresar(){
    //alert('regresando')
    window.location.href='index.php' 
}
```

La idea es que al momento de presionar el botón de inicio me mande a la pagina de `index` pero no lo hace me da el error **Not Found**

> The requested URL /ventas/vistas/index.php was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.39 (Win32) PHP/7.2.18 Server at localhost Port 80

El `index` esta en la raíz del proyecto mientras la vista de registro de usuarios esta en una carpeta llamada vistas.

Comment: Hola Angel, el problema es que estas dentro de la carpeta vistas.y intentas buscar el archivo index.php que no existe.
Tienes dos opciones 1: usar un / para indicar que se use tu carpeta raíz: window.location.href='/index.php' o 2: usar ../ para indicar que el index.php se encuentra en la carpeta superior : window.location.href='../index.php'. con eso deberia ser suficiente. Espero te ayude-. saludos.

Comment: Cuando colocas solo el nombre del archivo, significa que el archivo está en la misma carpeta que el que estás modificando.

Comment: Gracias, funciono perfectamente